# How I change the option name on select field of backpack-for-laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

How I can set the option name up without change the value.  I mean.

With this code

```
$this->crud->addField([
            'name'=>'idtype',
            'label'=>'Tipo de Documento',
            'type'=>'enum'
        ]);
```

I got this

```
<option value="CC">CC</option>
```

I want to get this

```
<option value="CC">Cédula de Ciudadanía</option>
```

Comment: 'attribute' => 'column name of the text that has to be shown' does not work?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain myself well

This is a select field.

Comment: Yes, try to add that property to the array

Comment: I tried this   'attribute' => ['Cédula de Ciudadanía','Cédula Extranjería','Pasaporte']
and
'attribute' => ['CC'=>'Cédula de Ciudadanía','CE'=>'Cédula Extranjería','PP'=>'Pasaporte']
 but not work.     I'm using backpack 3.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using the [select_from_array](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.0/crud-fields#select-from-array) field type instead of select. This field type allows you to explicitly define what the `<options>` for that select input will be:

```php
$this->crud->addField([   // select_from_array
    'name' => 'template',
    'label' => "Template",
    'type' => 'select_from_array',
    'options' => [‘one’ => ‘One’, ‘two’ => ‘Two’],
    'allows_null' => false,
    'default' => 'one',
    // 'allows_multiple' => true, // OPTIONAL; needs you to cast this to array in your model;
]);
```

Notice the `options` argument takes in an array. You can manually define that array to say whatever you want, but have the array keys the same values as what your ENUM db column can hold.